# How to print SI unit in rrdtool graph print?

Tags: rrdtool, rrd

According Documentation

> %s or %S will add the appropriate SI unit ,

But when added or not added , PRINT is printing only the value but
not if the value is Mbps or Gbps,

command with %s or %S

`rrdtool graph dummy -e 00:00 DEF:test="Bandwidth.rrd":1:MAX PRINT:test:MAX:%5.2lf%S`

output

`0x0
55.20`

command without %s

`rrdtool graph dummy -e 00:00 DEF:test="Bandwidth.rrd":1:MAX PRINT:test:MAX:%5.2lf`

output

`0x0
55.20`

I need it to print to the console that whether the value is in Mbps or Gbps,

Comment: Which version of rrdtool are you using ? rrdtool --version

Comment: @montardon RRDTool 1.4.9

Comment: I guess if no G, M, m or whatever gets added, your values are in non-G, M or m range, ie 55.20 bps?